# To draw a rectangle around the object

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on object detection in the video. I have 5 to 6 objects approx in each frame and i detect corner points of each object. Now how is that i can determine the exterior boundary of each object using corner points only.

Comment: Please add an image containing the objects, and the code you used so far

Comment: Where these points come from? Are they already grouped by object? If yes, just use cv::boundingRect. Regarding the separation of two nearby objects, you're not going to make it like this... What if it's a long truck instead of two cars?

Comment: @Miki these are corner points. no, they aren't grouped. I want to group them to a particular object and draw its surroundings.

Comment: Corner points of what? How are going to group them robustly? Don't you have the background mask or something?

Comment: @Miki. Corner points of the objects. Yes i do have.!! After background mask i found the corner points of the object.

Comment: So use Findcontours on the binary mask, and compute boundingRect on each contour.

Comment: Post binary mask, btw

Comment: @Miki i have done that i got a problem of merging of two objects there. So has to use features of each object to  avoid merging. Okay i ll post ma binary image.

Comment: You can't. What if it's a truck, and not 2 cars?

Comment: @Miki Once after i get ma binary image i ll do "AND" operation with ma original video.  Now i ll be left with  the vehicles. Extracting features of each vehicle and grouping them can't address merging it??

Comment: Probably not. Good luck with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can loop over each corner point and find the max and min values.

Example:

```
    //includes
#include<vector>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

//defines
#define INFINITY ((1e+300)*(1e+300))
#define MIN(x,y) ((x)<(y)?(x):(y))
#define MAX(x,y) ((x)>(y)?(x):(y))

struct SBoundary {
    float top, bottom, left, right;
};

struct SPoint {
    SPoint(float _x,float _y):x(_x),y(_y) {}
    float x, y;
};

float PointDistance(SPoint& p1, SPoint& p2) {
    return sqrt((p2.x - p1.x)*(p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y)*(p2.y - p1.y));
}
const float maxDistance = 2.0/*find an appropiate minimum distance between points*/;

vector<vector<SPoint>> seperateObjects(vector<SPoint> Points) {
    vector<vector<SPoint>> Objects;

    vector<SPoint>::iterator it = Points.begin();
    while (Points.size() != 0) {
        SPoint buffer = Points[0];
        it = Points.erase(Points.begin());//erase first point from list - function return iterator for next element

        vector<SPoint> newObject;
        newObject.push_back(buffer);

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < newObject.size(); i++) {
           vector<SPoint>::iterator it3 = Points.begin();
           while (it3 != Points.end()) {
                float _distance = PointDistance(newObject[i], *it3);
                 if (_distance <= maxDistance) {//point belongs to Object
                    newObject.push_back(*it3);
                    it3 = Points.erase(it3); //process this point only once - function return iterator for next element
                }
                else {
                    it3++;
                }
            }
        }

        Objects.push_back(newObject);
    }

    return Objects;

}

SBoundary findBoundaries(vector<SPoint> vertices) {

    SBoundary Boundary;

    Boundary.top = INFINITY;
    Boundary.bottom = -INFINITY;
    Boundary.left = INFINITY;
    Boundary.right = -INFINITY;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertices.size();i++) {
        Boundary.top = MIN(Boundary.top, vertices[i].y);
        Boundary.bottom = MAX(Boundary.bottom, vertices[i].y);

        Boundary.left = MIN(Boundary.left, vertices[i].x);
        Boundary.right = MAX(Boundary.right, vertices[i].x);
    }

    return Boundary;
}
```

You can use these functions like this:

```
vector<SBoundary> findAllBoundaries(vector<SPoint> Points) {

    vector<SBoundary> Boundaries;
    vector<vector<SPoint>> Objects = seperateObjects(Points);

    for (unsigned int i = 0;i < Objects.size();i++) {
        Boundaries.push_back(findBoundaries(Objects[i]));
    }
    return Boundaries;
}
```

Now all you have to do is to invoke this function and pass a vector of your corner points as the argument and you will return your Boundary Boxes.

The `maxDistance` constant should be set to a value that represents the maximum Distance between two points belonging to the same Object and being next to each other.

Example Point set (works fine with `maxDistance = 2.0`):

```
vector<SPoint> points;

points.push_back(SPoint(1.0, 1.0));
points.push_back(SPoint(2.0, 2.0));
points.push_back(SPoint(3.0, 3.0));
points.push_back(SPoint(4.0, 2.0));
points.push_back(SPoint(1.0, 3.0));
points.push_back(SPoint(8.0, 5.0));
points.push_back(SPoint(10.0, 6.0));
points.push_back(SPoint(9.0, 6.0));
points.push_back(SPoint(8.0, 7.0));

vector<SBoundary> boundaries = findAllBoundaries(points);
```

This set of points would result into two Objects, and the function return the proper Bounding Box for them.

Objects:

1. {1, 1}, { 2,2 }, { 1,3 }, { 4,2 }, { 3,3 }
2. { 8,5 }, { 10,5 }, { 9,6 }, { 8,7 }

The order in which you give the points does not matter.

I hope my answer will help you.

Comment: Have you ever heard of OpenCV? While the concept in your answer may be the correct one (hard to tell from the question, actually) you're code is like reinventing the wheel

Comment: I think these colored dots are your corner points, aren't they? So you only have to use them as input to the function

Comment: @Philinator Thank you. Yes they are corner points. How is that i determine that these points belong to a single object so that i can give these points as an input to this function.

Comment: Ok i have edited my answer. I hope is is understandable.

Comment: @Arjun Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Philinator thank u so much for taking time on this. Actually ma system was down. Sorry for the late reply. I tried it but i got few errors. Do you want me to share the code?? I have stored all my points in vector named "corner" and also passed these points to your function. But couldn't work.

Comment: @Philinator I want that only. But I am getting plenty of errors with the code. Did i miss any header files??

Comment: Is your compiler able to compile c++11?

Comment: @Philinator there lies the problem i guess. Nope. I use VS 2010.

Comment: @Philinator your answer was useful sir. I have Up voted the answer. It ll display once i reach particular points on this stack.

Comment: @Arjun can you compile it now?

Comment: @Philinator I'm sorry for the trouble, Nope still its not..!! Error 6 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int.

Comment: @Arjun i have debugged the code with VS 2010 and i spotted a few mistakes. It should work now.

Comment: @Philinator Yes, it finally did the work for me. I'm getting the output but how did you display the grouped objects as u mentioned in the above?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Arjun do you mean how to Display the Bounding Box?

Comment: @Philinator yes.. i mean the same

Comment: @Arjun well if you take the output you have 4 values( top,bottom,left,right).

Comment: @Arjun now you can construct the lines of your Bounding box
line 1: (left,top) -> (right,top)
line 2: (left,bottom) -> (right,bottom)
line 3: (left,top) -> (left,bottom)
line 4: (right,top) -> (right,bottom)

Comment: @Arjun is that what you meant?

Comment: @Philinator for( auto i=0; i<boundaries.size();i++)
{
cout << boundaries[i].top << " " << boundaries[i].bottom << " " << boundaries[i].right << " " << boundaries[i].left;
cout << " \n " ;

}                   

This is what i did before.
I got 2 groups of each  4 values (top,bottom,right,left).
What shall i infer from it?

Comment: @Arjun Sorry but i don't really understand what you wanna do

Comment: @Arjun now you can construct the lines of your Bounding box line 1: (left,top) -> (right,top) line 2: (left,bottom) -> (right,bottom) line 3: (left,top) -> (left,bottom) line 4: (right,top) -> (right,bottom)
here you have the 4 lines of the bounding box.

Comment: @Philinator No i just want to display the points in two different groups like u did..!!

Comment: @Arjun if you only want to Display the Points in different Groups then you should only invoke the ``seperateObjects` function which outputs a vector of your "Objects". this vector contains a vector of different vectors. the latter represents your objects and contains all their points

Comment: @Arjun so you can do it like {
vector<SPoint> points = ...;
...
vector<vector<SPoint>> objects = seperateObjects(points);

for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++)
             draw(object[i]);

}

Comment: @Arjun your welcome! i hope the solution works as you wanted it to.

Comment: I think if you want to have distinction between close objects you're going to need to train a deep learning algorithm with vehicles, features are not enough.

Comment: @Philinator Perfectly done..!! I would like to show u my results.!! Still a part of work need to be done..!!  I would like to show the results of this part.!!

Comment: @aledalgrande I don't know how to use deep learning..!! Should i have a data sets to train it??

Comment: @Arjun It would make me happy if you could show me your results.

Comment: @Arjun look in my Profile. I have posted my mail id there. Please send me a message when you have seen it so that i can delete it from my profile page again.

Comment: @Philinator Yes !! You can take it off now.